# @Angular 2: Better approach Whether to create components or modules

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-modules

**@angular2,  @angular2-components,  @angular2-modules**

What would be better approach whether to create ***child modules of app module*** or ***different components*** for different features of project using `angular2` from design and business perspective ?

Comment: Modules used to specify some independent feature of Your app and modules can have its components: `module -> component`

Comment: it is too broad a question , modules contains components and directives . i guess you  are confused with Angular JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng modules simply logical units that contained components, services, pipes, directives, providers, etc.

The main benefit of ng modules is that they help you to organize the logical structure of your app - this way is much easier to maintain the codebase over time, etc.

There is a different types of modules:

- feature module https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-09
- shared module https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-10
- core module https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-11

A while ago I was [giving a talk](https://kuncevic.github.io/presentations/ng-modules-lazy-loading-and-fun-with-bundle-analyzing.html) on that matter also you might take a look at [code sample](https://github.com/kuncevic/angular-modular-project-structure)

Also I would recommend to watch this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o from the latest ngconf that covers the purpose of ng modules.

Comment: thanks for it, this is the thing what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If you are looking for building your own framework and use it in other projects, it is good to create a feature module (separate module). For example, if you have a `sidebar` component and you want to use that very same component in another application, keep it in a separate module.

Practically, a module contains components. So, if a `AddComponent`, `SubComponent`, `MultiplyComponent` etc. all satisfy a single business unit like `Math`, you should consider creating a `MathModule`.

If you are looking for building a single module application, go ahead there is no hard and fast rules. But consider a nice feature of Angular module. A module can also be loaded on demand. So, if you are looking for loading some components lazily, you have to wrap them in a module. There is no other way.